# Continue appending [to stream] in for-loop without local variable access

Tags: c++11, for-loop, logging, lambda

Imagine you have the following code where `logDebug()` is expensive or is not appropriate to call more than once:

```
QDebug d = logDebug();
d << __FUNCTION__ << ":";
d << "positions separated with \" --- \":";
for (const auto& str : positions)
{
    d << "---" << str;
}
```

A macro (just to replace the function name correctly) already exists which replaces the first 2 lines:

```
#define LOG_FUNCTION  this->logDebug() <<  __FUNCTION__ << ":"
```

It creates the local variable by calling `logDebug()`. Once called, you can only use the `operator<<` onto the macro.
The problem is you can't attach the for loop body to logger.

Q: Is there a way I could use the macro for pasting all the positions (without calling `logDebug` again?
I would guess this should be possible using lambdas, but I quite don't know how to.
Please help, the shortest answer wins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: Is there a way I could use the macro for pasting all the positions (without calling logDebug again? I would guess this should be possible using lambdas, but I quite don't know how to.

I suppose it's possible with something as follows (used `std::cout` instead of `logDebug()`)

```
#include <iostream>

#define LOG_FUNCTION  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": "

#define LOG_DEB(ps) \
    [](auto & s, auto const & _ps) { for ( auto const & p : _ps ) s << p; } \
    (LOG_FUNCTION, ps)

int main ()
 {
   int  a[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

   LOG_DEB(a);
 }
```

I've used a couple of `auto` as types of the lambda arguments and this works only starting from C++14.

In C++11 you have to replace they with the correct types.

Comment: Cool! I've never seen this type of lambda, with brackets after the curly braces. This `auto` is cool here, and could be replaced by a template I guess.

Comment: @DrumM - Well... no. Isn't a different types of lambda. It's a lambda definition (until the curly braces) immediately called (with arguments `std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": (etc not repeated part) "` and `ps`). And no, `auto` can't be replaced by a template (at the moment... maybe starting from C++20) but you can see it as a template (it's syntactic sugar for a template `operator()` in an unnamed struct); if you need to know the type of `s`, you can use `decltype(s)`. Unfortunately `auto` (as type of lambda argument) is available only starting from C++14.

Comment: I understand now. A good update here would be to use a different name for the second `ps` symbol as they are different. It was confusing when reading it for the first time ;-) Anyway, this is a very nice piece of code!

Comment: @DrumM - You're right: good update; not because confusing but because it's the name of parameter of the macro. It was a very dangerous error.

Answer (score 1):

Well the macro can be coerced to return your debug object:

```
#define LOG_FUNCTION()  this->logDebug() <<  __FUNCTION__ << ":"
```

Then use it like this:

```
auto& d = LOG_FUNCTION();
d << "positions separated with \" --- \":";
for (const auto& str : positions)
{
    d << "---" << str;
}
```